# How to retrieve data for angularjs expression from json?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a json response i want to populate data into fields how i can achieve that task using angularjs expression.how i would map values from json response to html page.

so far i tried this...

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label">Rule Id</label>
        <div>{{ruleIdentifier}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="control-label">SubpartID</label>
        <div>{{subpartId}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

MODALCTRL.JS

```
lrrDetails.findlrrDetail().then(function(response){
  $scope.lrrDetail = response;
  $scope.ruleidentifier = $scope.lrrDetail.id
})
```

FACTORY.JS

```
findlrrDetail: function(result){
        return $http.get('/third-party-management/rest/lrr/17181');
        $scope.lrrDetail = result.data;
    },
```

JSON.JS

```
    {"id":1,
"sourceFeedKey":15,
"lookupCode":"RS_DELETED",
"externalIndintifier":"47",
"subpartCitationIndicator":"1",
"ruleIdentifier":"13",
"ruleSubpartExternalIdentifier":"55029",
"subpartCount":null,
"subpartCitationCount":null,
"citationValue":"18 U.S.C. 2711",
"ruleName":"Definitions For Chapter",
"highValueSummary":"This chapter provides guidance on stored wire and electronic communications and transactional records access and contains provisions of the Stored Communications 
Act.","
issuingAuthKey":873,
"citationAsOfDate":1325566800000,
"vedourActivityType":"Internal Activity",
"vedourActivityDescription1":null,
"vedourActivityDescription2":null,
"applicabilityIndicator":"0",
"auditGroupCategory":null,
"auditGroupIndicator":null,
"citationCoreIndicator":null,
"createdDate":1352497145890,
"modifiedDate":1375313477250,
"createdBy":"ERDSYSTEM",
"mofifiedBy":"NBKQNXS",
"regulatoryInventoryName"
```

Comment: Aftab, Can you please rewrite your question. I really can't understand what are you looking for.

Comment: vagueness edited please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to work with `$http` and how to populate the data. Hopefully it works for you. 
http://jsfiddle.net/8qumcq80/1/

Comment: i can not use jsfiddle and plunker for some security reason do you have an yother source

Comment: Sun!:) ,it's better to open the example in chrome. Anyhow, I pasted the example in jsbin.com. you can see the output in http://jsbin.com/cinejayagu/1  and the code can be accessible via this url:http://jsbin.com/cinejayagu/1/edit?html,js,output